# How to delay/stop order emails

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status

I would like to stop order emails when order placed in Magento store.

Actually, the whole idea is to send an email when order placed with "We've received an order and will let you know asap."

After this email admin will review the order and then if it's fine then he'll approve the order and later on default system will handle it.

How can I **achieve** this?

I've come up with an idea to create new order status I've only offline payment methods in my store.

Is any idea/hint will be appreciated.

**PS: For now not willing to use any extension.**

Comment: Hey Why down-vote ! Please explain

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Email from Order Section Sales Email by doing Enabled to No in dropdown.

Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email -> Order -> Enabled

You can also disable other emails configurations here like Invoice.

By sending order email after review you can do by adding a button click.